# const function signature from function signature

Tags: c++, function, constants, typedef, signature

```
typedef void fv();
typedef std::add_const<fv>::type fvc;

typedef void fv_const() const;
static_assert(std::is_same<fvc,fv_const>::value,"Oops");
```

This doesn't compile because because `fvc` and `fv_const` are not the same types.

Is it possible to derive the type `fvc` from `fv` so that it equals `fv_const`?

Comment: What _is_ a const-qualified non-member function?

Comment: No, it isn't because you can construct member functions from it: `struct A { fv MemFn; fvc ConstMemFn; };`.

Comment: What is a const-qualified non-member function? >> _No, ..._ >> Huh?

Comment: You can't construct member functions from it, member functions have a different calling convention `thiscall` as opposed to static and non-member functions. What you are trying to do is non-sensical.

You should post your real requirement, not what you **think** is the solution.

Comment: Sorry, mistook your user name as an answer to your question.

Comment: Defining member functions like in my previous comment is allowed by the standard. Add `void A::MemFn() {}` and compile.

Comment: What are you using this for?  `const`-qualification on non-member functions isn't particularly useful.

Comment: @ecatmur Using `fv` and `fvc` I can define class member functions as described above. And also the types of these member functions (`T::mv` and `T::mvc`). And I can define functions that take an `mv` or `mvc` and a `T*` or `const T*` and bind them to return a `std::function<fv>`. All this and I only need to specify the signature once. So changes to the signature `fv` require a lot less work. Only the implementations of the various T member functions need to change their signatures. And the compiler finds them without flooding the output with template errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `const` to non-member function signatures doesn't make much sense, but you can do it:

```
template<class T> struct add_f_const;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct add_f_const<R (Args...)> { typedef R type(Args...) const; };

static_assert(std::is_same<add_f_const<void()>::type, void() const>::value, "Oops");
```

It's more usual to add `const` to member functions:

```
template<class T> struct add_member_const;
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
struct add_member_const<R (T::*)(Args...)> { using type = R (T::*)(Args...) const; };

struct test {};
static_assert(std::is_same<add_member_const<void (test::*)()>::type,
  void (test::*)() const>::value,  "Oops");
```

Comment: @user2170200 just write another type modifier that handles non-member function types; see above.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Though I had to replace the variadic templates with a couple of overloads.